# How to show each record in new row?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've tried to use XSL to output the list all of the orders in a XML file but there is no break lines between values

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="qty" match="quantity" use="id_order"/>  

<xsl:template match="/">
<output>
    <orders>

        <xsl:for-each select="output/orders/order"> 
            <order>

                <xsl:copy-of select="id|number|type|KG|PAL|M3"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('qty', id)">
                    <xsl:element name="{unit}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>  
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </order>    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </orders>
</output>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="quantity">
<amount><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></amount>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can i display every record in new row?

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version= "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="display.xls"?>
<output>
<orders>
    <order>
        <id>1</id>
        <number>10002</number>
        <type>Loading</type>
        <date>2013-01-01T02:30:00</date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>2</id>
        <number>10003</number>
        <type>Loading</type>
        <date>2013-01-01T010:30:00</date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>3</id>
        <number>10004</number>
        <type>Loaded</type>
        <date>2013-01-01T12:30:00</date>
    </order>
</orders>
<quantities>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>1</id_order>
        <unit>KG</unit>
        <value>1000</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>1</id_order>
        <unit>PAL</unit>
        <value>3</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>1</id_order>
        <unit>M3</unit>
        <value>1.5</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>2</id_order>
        <unit>KG</unit>
        <value>2000</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>2</id_order>
        <unit>PAL</unit>
        <value>4</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>3</id_order>
        <unit>KG</unit>
        <value>5000</value> 
    </quantity>
</quantities>
</output>
```

I've tryed something with table but with no success..

Comment: I think you want an HTML output to display in browser.. Currently the output is XML. Correct your XSL to produce an HTML output adding "<br/>" for new line or however you want it to be

Answer (score 0):

```
&#xa; or &#10;  =  LF character
&#xd; or &#13;  =  CR character
```

If your out put is xml then put the following line where you need it

```
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
or
<xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
```